# Выборка из MySQL: сначала по условию, затем остальные

Tags: mysql, запрос, выборка

Здравствуйте.

Такая сложная для меня задачка.

Нужно из БД MySQL выбрать 10 записей. Причём, обязательно выбрать записи, где соблюдается условие some_field=1, а если таковых будет менее 10, то оставшиеся дополнить любыми первыми попавшимися (по id например).

То бишь, в выборке, к примеру, может получиться только 4 записи с some_field=1, и тогда надо будет в неё добавить 6 любых записей.

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно составить запрос.

Comment: `select * from table order by some_field=1 desc limit 10`

Comment: @Mike спасибо))) всё, сорри, сутки за компом, туплю))) делаю where some_field=1 вместо order by

Comment: @Mike и на индексы забиваем

Comment: @AntonShchyrov А тут полюбому без индексов. БД не использует индекс при поиске `some_field <> 1` - это же полный перебор индекса кроме одной ветки, а выборка всех записей таблицы по индексу кроме некоторых раз в 10 дольше прямого сканирования таблицы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через подзапрос с `UNION`.

Выбираем 10 нужных, дополняем 10 ненужными, отбираем первые 10

```mysql
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    0 AS `order`,
    *
  FROM
    my_table
  WHERE
    some_field = 1
  LIMIT
    10
  UNION
  SELECT
    1 AS `order`,
    *
  FROM
    my_table
  WHERE
    some_field <> 1
  LIMIT
    10
) sub
ORDER BY
  `order`
LIMIT
  10
```

Comment: Я в комментарии к вопросу написал правильный вариант. А UNION по стандарту SQL НЕ гарантирует что записи на выходе будут в порядке выборок. Порядок гарантирует  _только_ ORDER BY

Comment: А это вообще в точности то, что мне нужно, благодарю! Попробовал - работает.

Comment: @АлександрВладимирович Работает до поры до времени, пока в очередной версии MySQL не решат переделать оптимизатор и он нарушит порядок выборки

Comment: @Mike, учёл. MySQL пока только изучаю, поэтому, рад любым пояснениям. Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: @Mike переделал запрос с учетом вариации `UNION`

Comment: а в данном случае я же тогда могу сначала отобрать some_field = 1, а если не хватает, то other_field = 2, то есть сделать order by some_field=1 or other_field=2  и т.д.? или это не правильно с точки зрения синтаксиса mysql?

Comment: @АлександрВладимирович Почему неправильно? Вы можете добавлять сколько угодно UNION секций (только не забывайте указывать ключ сортировки)